# Send push notification to target device with fcmToken on Android Project with Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, cloud, messaging

The logs I putted to the code seems that the app working correctly and send the notifications to the target device, but I think that I'm doing something wrong, because even the logs said that the notification sent correctly, didn't ever appear to the device.

Some additional info:

- I have turned on the notification for the app on (i have turned on for two devices and 1 emulator device but nowhere worked)
- the fcmToken is correct because I did a test notification message from the Firebase Console and the notification came successfully.

Firstly, I want to inform you for the structure of my Realtime database:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The fcmToken for each user is retrieved from the registration of the user on UserActivity with the code:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()
                                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
                                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                    String fcmToken = task.getResult();

                                                    writeNewUserToDatabase(mAuth.getUid(),
                                                            emailET.getText().toString(),
                                                            fullNameET.getText().toString(),
                                                            lat,
                                                            lng,
                                                            fcmToken);
                                                } else {
                                                    Log.d("MyApp", "Failed to get FCM token: " + task.getException().getMessage());
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
```

So, now every registered user has a fcmToken.
At the AdminActivity now i have a button in an AlertDialog that calls the findNearbyUsers() method  when clicked.

findNearbyUsers() (AdminActivity):

```
private void findNearbyUsers(Alert alert) {
        DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("USER");

        usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                Set<String> nearbyTokens = new HashSet<>();

                for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    double userLat = userSnapshot.child("lat").getValue(Double.class);
                    double userLng = userSnapshot.child("lng").getValue(Double.class);
                    String userToken = userSnapshot.child("fcmToken").getValue(String.class);
                    // Calculate the distance between the user and the alert
                    float[] results = new float[1];
                    Location.distanceBetween(alert.getLat(), alert.getLng(), userLat, userLng, results);

                    // Check if the user is nearby (within 1 kilometer)
                    if (results[0] <= 1000) {
                        nearbyTokens.add(userToken);
                    }
                }

                // Send push notifications to all nearby users
                sendNotificationToUsers(nearbyTokens, alert);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Log.e("LoG", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });
    }
```

sendNotificationToUsers() (AdminActivity)

```
private void sendNotificationToUsers(Set<String> tokens, Alert alert) {
        // Create the notification channel
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("CHANNEL_ID", "Channel Name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        // Build the notification message
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "CHANNEL_ID")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setContentTitle("Alert nearby!")
                .setContentText("An alert has been verified near your location.")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        // Create the intent to open the app when the user taps on the notification
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AdminActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        // Send the notification to each nearby user on a background thread
        new Thread(() -> {
            for (String token : tokens) {
                if (token == null || token.isEmpty()) {
                    return;
                }

                Log.d("FCM", "Sending notification to FCM token(sendMessage): " + token);
                Log.d("FCM", "Notification title: " + alert.getTitle());
                Log.d("FCM", "Notification message: " + alert.getDescription());


                FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(new RemoteMessage.Builder(token)
                        .setMessageId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                        .addData("title", alert.getTitle())
                        .addData("message", alert.getDescription())
                        .build());
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

The logs i got from clicking the button that calls the findNearbyUsers() are:

D/FCM: Sending notification to FCM token(sendMessage): cly-c8S9SpSHsd6_pIrVDw:APA91bGkqMK5AYCJyWad_1cQlDRjOaqVSO...
Notification title: 1@flood
D/FCM: Notification message: j
D/FCM: Sending notification to FCM token(sendMessage): ck3P3SCbSHurWVHZ4o8Czy:APA91bFbU66AoYwrvlM2gkdR3vtD52rT7qeJU8Ig7-ds7HKPQC4BM7ftLHeQSQca47zBHSG3UQjyXsbQav2aEjK...
D/FCM: Notification title: 1@flood
D/FCM: Notification message: j
D/FCM: Sending notification to FCM token(sendMessage): eVuZsrTWQwyElN8BhEmtC7:APA91bFXF4EBytwy158204Tav9nzqLIPwo_7HzX1K5Qgo4RjcMRTuX2ca-GG78FCpqYAt1Bp2PJngsXP4wdMtqrYRop...
D/FCM: Notification title: 1@flood
D/FCM: Notification message: j

It seems to me that the notifications successfully sent to devices but never got them appearing.

PS: I tried to use Firebase Admin SDK but the whole code i wrote had errors so I removed it and I don't want to use it.